# What is an appropriate BFS-like optimal path algorithm for multiple entrances and multiple exits?

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization, path-finding, breadth-first-search

I'm searching for an optimal path algorithm that finds the optimal path from any of the start-nodes to the closest exit-nodes.

The graph in this case is a square grid and all costs to a neighbour-square are 1.
Any optimizations using these restrictions are fine.

Basically you enter the square grid from a randomly chosen entrance, now you want to find the closest path to any of the given exits.

Until now I'm doing BFS multiple times, once for every exit and combine the results. Though I doubt this is the most performant way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do BFS starting at all the exits.  When you discover a new square, it's distance to the closest exit is the previous square's distance +1, and the path direction is towards the previous square.

Since none of the (distance,direction) tuples depends on where you enter, you can precalculate these values for all squares once, so you don't have to redo the search if you start again at a new entrance.

Comment: But isn't this kind of what I'm doing? Doing a BFS multiple times? Since BFS usually only has one start? Maybe I get you wrong though.

Comment: One BFS, starting with _OUTSIDE_ as a root, which is connected to all the exit squares, which are connected to their neighbors, etc.